# ArcGIS GeoProcessing Model - Store List of Altered Features in Database

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, geoprocessing, modelbuilder

I am trying to build a GeoProcessing model which will find any parcels that have had their geometry values changed and store the corresponding parcel numbers in a separate non-spatial table.  I am using ArcGIS 10.

Does anyone know of any python scripts that would accomplish these tasks?  One potential solution I found is the [Compare Layer to Snapshot](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Compare_Layer_to_Snapshot/010900000016000000/) tool.  Even though this is listed in the ArcGIS Resource Center, I can not find it in my version of ArcMap.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You might take a look at the ArcGIS [Feature Compare](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000004000000.htm) tool.  It supposedly should do the trick, however I have had a tough time using it unless you can sort both datasets so that they ordered exactly the same line-for-line, which is how it appears to compare the old-new datasets.

A while back I also created a [python script](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=C1327F2B-1422-2418-A06F-8E7269E0B312) that just compares geometry changes by doing a "SearchByLocation" is "Identical".  I just posted to the ArcGIS Resource Center Geoprocessing gallery if you want to take a look and modify to meet your specific needs.